# Real world examples of asynchronous iterators usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-iterator, ecmascript-2018

I would like to know some possible real world usage examples of [asynchronous iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration), part of ECMAScript 2018.

For readable streams it looks useful, since we would be able to iterate them easily using the new `for await of`. Actually, in Node.js, readable streams already have a `Symbol.asyncIterator` property implemented as an [experimental feature](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator):

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function print(readable) {
  readable.setEncoding('utf8');
  let data = '';
  for await (const k of readable) {
    data += k;
  }
  console.log(data);
}

print(fs.createReadStream('file')).catch(console.log);
```

But I couldn't think of some other good usages.

As for synchronous iterators, we have native objects like Array or Map, which include a `Symbol.iterator` property since ES2015, making them iterable. In this case I think their use is very extended and easy to understand.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: The proposal already lists readLines example, doesn't it? Any scenario is applicable where promises need to be lazily created on demand. A crawler, etc.

Comment: Every single `EventEmitter` (or DOM `EventTarget`) could be made into an async iterator.